# Open Sans won't display bolder than 700 in Chrome

Tags: css, fonts

I came across a weird issue where everything displays fine in Safari, but in Chrome my H1 will not display bolder than 600. Even if I change it in developer tools -  for this page http://station-studios.com/visual-brand-design/

However on the about page it does display properly. 
http://station-studios.com/about/

If I change the font to ex. Source Sans Pro it is fine on both pages. CSS styles look the same for both. I am stumped.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about **web development** which is off-topic at Pro Webmasters. Web development questions may be asked at [so] but be sure to read their [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/help) before posting to ensure your question meets their guidelines. In its current form it will not as the question should contains the code you use and images of its effect, not links to your website.